# How to get recent documents in sharepoint mysite

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I wanted to fetch the latest documents from the skydrive pro of SharePoint 2013. Is there any api access to get this?

The image below shows the recent documents for a user. I need to fetch the same data for one of my custom webparts [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Skydrive-Pro gives direct access to your own Libraries on your own My-Sites.

Based on that, I would go for a search-based solution coupling where using Modified-By / Created-By with Current User (some examples http://benprins.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/sharepoint-2013-search-tips-and-tricks also for KQ property restriction samples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx#kql_property_restriction_queries), plus the search restrictions pointing only to Documents from My-Sites wildcard path used.

Comment: Thanks, this will work for me now. However I am not able to see the "Recent Documents" under my profile photo as shown in the pic above.

Comment: i would say that is matter of master page configuration as the Quick launch from the My-Site seems to have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/me/getrecentdocs` to get this using REST. Depending on your call headers you can get it in JSON or as XML.